# Teradata Determine First Day of Year

Tags: sql, teradata

Is there a way to determine the first day of a year in Teradata SQL?

For example, I use this to find the first day of the month:

```
SELECT dt + (1 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM dt)) AS dt
```

I know I can extract the year directly using `YEAR()` but I want to output the results as a date so it will work in some external charts.

I tried this, but it added a bunch of spaces at the start of the date:

```
CONCAT(YEAR(dt),'-01-01')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
ADD_MONTHS(dt, -(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt) - 1)) + (1 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM dt))
```

Answer (score 4):

dnoeth's approach is cool for long term optimization of jobs, but, in my opinion, the simple answer is either Jeffrey's or the following.  Not sure which one uses less resources:

```
select cast(extract(year from current_date)||'0101' as date format 'yyyymmdd');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and elegant 
      TRUNC(current_date, 'Y')

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is based on internal storage and can easily be put into SQL-UDFs:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION first_day_of_year(yr INTEGER)
RETURNS DATE
SPECIFIC first_day_of_year_INT
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
   (yr - 1900) * 10000 + 101 (DATE)
;
REPLACE FUNCTION first_day_of_year(cdate DATE)
RETURNS DATE
SPECIFIC first_day_of_year_DT
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
   first_day_of_year(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate))
;
```

Edit:

Since TD14.10 there's `TRUNC(dt, 'Y')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> select date- dayofyear(date)+1